# Add default gateway while installing Debian

Tags: debian-squeeze, routing

I have in my virtual infrastructure static ip addresses and have to set the gateway which following commands:

```
post-up route add x.x.x.254 dev eth0
post-up route add default gw x.x.x.254
post-down route del x.x.x.254 dev eth0
post-down route del default gw x.x.x.254
```

Is there any possibility to set them with in the netinstaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a shell from the installer main menu and do the networking setup by hand. Then continue with the next installer step after the network setup.

Comment: I had forgotten that I can add routes with the BusyBox.

Answer (score 0):

Press [Alt] + [F2] for the second terminal. To enable it, press [Enter] and add the routes with following commands:

```
route add x.x.x.254 dev eth0
route add default gw x.x.x.254
```